# Why wasn't my question fully answered?

Tags: support, asking

Take my question:
[How likely is it that an Xbox 360 hard drive will die, and are there any early warning signs or indicators?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13531/360-hard-drive-failure)

I asked for people with experience in hard drive failure, but I got a few comments from people that didn't actually experienced what I asked for. I may accept one of their answer as they go around the problem and offer useful advices, but I simply didn't get what I asked for (and what somebody else may look for when reading the answers). The question is more than 3 months old, so I don't think I will receive more answers. What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, essentially, your question is unclear. It can be one of three questions.

#### Has anyone else's XBox 360 Hard Drive died? Doesn't it Suck?

- This is a Bad Question. It is essentially a poll, and provides no new or useful information. It is essentially a rant, poorly disguised as a question, seeking not so much an answer as *affirmation or agreement.* It should be closed as Subjective and Argumentative.

#### Can the XBox 360's Hard Drive die? How likely is it, are there any early warning signs or indicators, and what can I do to protect my data against this possibility?

- This is actually a pretty good question. If this is what you're asking, you need to clarify your question to indicate that.

#### My XBox 360's Hard Drive died. What do I do?

- This is the other way the question could be read. This is a Good Question as well, and could provide a pretty useful answer.

As of now, your question is singularly unclear. It could be any of those three, or it could be something else entirely. Until you figure out which it is, I've voted to close it as Not A Real Question. I'd encourage you to think about what sort of information you're actually after, and clarify your question to make that intent more apparent.

Comment: I have edited my question to match your second option (which is what I actually meant from the beginning, will take more care next time)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, your question "really" asked: "have you experienced a HDD crash on an XBox 360?"

That question is bad subjective, because it's practically a poll. That's why it has been ignored.

Answer (score 2):

The only useful formulation of this is to find sources of actual large-scale data on Xbox 360 hard drive failures..

These are just standard 2.5" HDDs so you might look at aggregated data on modern(ish) 2.5" laptop HDD failure rates across a few different vendors that MSFT is known to use.

Comment: Here again, this is not exactly the answer of my question (maybe I formulated it incorrectly?). I'm not asking about the failure of the COMPONENT, but about the failure of the SYSTEM. What happened to your system? Did you get early warning from dashboard? Did you were able to recover your saves?

Comment: The question **title** is *hard drive failure*.  If you did not mean hard drive failure, you should not have written it.

Comment: @michelemarcon That's the very definition of a bad subjective question, as per badp's answer.